# Data from three .txt files - loop together to one, and make a plot?

Tags: python, loops

I want to end up with a scatterplot that differentiates color between different values.
First i need to analyze my data. Problem is i have a FE-Model, that exports element numbers coupled with 4 nodes. These 4 nodes have 4 coordinate sets, but if 4 elements share 1 node, it will only give 1 coordinate set for these 4 nodes.

I end up with three .txt files.

1. .txt with element number (and data i am analyzing for the plot)
2. .txt with the element number and node numbers.
3. .txt with node coordinates.

Is it possible to make a loop that connects these datapoints?
I would like to include an example, but i have not yet made one.
I have tried something like this

```
from numpy import loadtxt

from fpdf import FPDF



Sek = ['Sektion_100']
I = 0
HeaderY =['nr.','LC','Element nr.','Myy','Nyy','MRd_y','URy']
HeaderX =['nr.','LC','Element nr.','Mxx','Nxx','MRd_x','URx']
#load the excel file
#header = loadtxt"Loads\Area_233.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)

pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'P', unit = 'mm', format = 'A4')
MaxURx =[]
MaxURy =[]

data = loadtxt("Loads/Sektion_150.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)
nr = data[:,1]
Mxx = data[:,2]
Nxx = -data[:,4]
Myy = data[:,3]
Nyy = -data[:,5]

topologi = loadtxt("Loads/Sektion_150_topologi.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)
nr1 = topologi[:,0]
node1 = topologi[:,1]
node2 = topologi[:,2]
node3 = topologi[:,3]
node4 = topologi[:,4]

knuder = loadtxt("Loads/Sektion_150_knuder.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)
nr2 = knuder[:,0]
x = knuder[:,1]
y = knuder[:,2]
z = knuder[:,3]
```

[Picture of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nODBm.png)

I have included a picture of my dataset here. In "Sektion_150_Knuder" NR = Node number.
I hope anyone have some pointers in the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
import xlwings as xw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from numpy import loadtxt
import numpy as np
from fpdf import FPDF
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter




Sek = ['Sektion_100','Sektion_110','Sektion_120','Sektion_130','Sektion_140','Sektion_150']
I = 0
HeaderY =['nr.','LC','Element nr.','Myy','Nyy','MRd_y','URy']
HeaderX =['nr.','LC','Element nr.','Mxx','Nxx','MRd_x','URx']
#load the excel file
#header = loadtxt"Loads\Area_233.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)

pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'P', unit = 'mm', format = 'A4')
MaxURx =[]
MaxURy =[]


Elem = np.array(loadtxt("Element/Sektion_100_elements.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1))
Node = np.array(loadtxt("Element/Sektion_100_nodes.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1))

#Elem = np.array(loadtxt("Element/"+Sek+"_elements.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1))
#Node = np.array(loadtxt("Element/"+Sek+"_nodes.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1))
data = loadtxt("Loads/Sektion_100.txt", unpack=False, skiprows=1)
Mxx = data[:,2]
Nxx = -data[:,4]
Myy = data[:,3]
Nyy = -data[:,5]

 
    
    
R1x = []
R2x = []
MRdx = []
URx = []
R1y = []
R2y = []
MRdy = []
URy = []
    
    
    

    
min_nx = int(round(max(min(Nxx),-300),-1)-10)
max_nx = int(round(max(Nxx),-1)+10)
min_ny = int(round(min(Nyy),-1)-10)
max_ny = int(round(max(Nyy),-1)+10)
xrange = range(min_nx, max_nx+50, round((max_nx+50-min_nx)/20))
yrange = range(min_ny, max_ny+50, round((max_ny+50-min_ny)/20))

    

x2 =range(0,len(data),1)

 


wbx =xw.Book("Capacity\\Sektion_100_L.xlsm", None, True)

sht_x1 = wbx.sheets["Beregning"]


    
for i in xrange:
    kx = sht_x1.range("N25").value = i
    Q1x = sht_x1["AV24"].value
    Q2x = sht_x1["BC24"].value
    R1x+=[Q1x]
    R2x+=[Q2x]    
    
   
for i in x2:
    if Myy[i] <= 0:
        
        mrdx = np.interp(Nxx[i],xrange,R1x)
        urx = Mxx[i] / mrdx
    else:
        mrdx = np.interp(Nxx[i],xrange,R2x)
        urx = Mxx[i] / mrdx
        
    MRdx += [round(mrdx,2)]
    URx += [round(urx,2)]

    

TabelX=np.c_[data[:,[0,1,2,4]],MRdx,URx]




sort_tabelX  = np.flipud(TabelX[TabelX[:,5].argsort()])

LimX = 25
        
for i in x2:
    if sort_tabelX[i,5] > 1.05 :
       LimX = i+2
    else:    
       break
LimX = max(25,LimX)
TABx=np.c_[list(range(1,LimX+1)),sort_tabelX[0:LimX,:]]
TABx2 = np.unique(TABx[:,2])
print(TABx2)
print(len(TABx2))

#OUE=np.array(TABx2)
#np.savetxt("array1.txt", TABx2)









# %%
NumOUE = len(TABx2)
NumElem = len(Elem)



EleRange = range(0,NumElem)
OUERange = range(0,NumOUE)
EO = np.searchsorted(Elem[:,0], TABx2)   
print(EO) 
EleCorOx =[]
EleCorOy =[]
EleCorOz =[]
EleCorUx =[]
EleCorUy =[]
EleCorUz =[]
for i in EleRange:
    
    Na = np.searchsorted(Node[:,0],Elem[i,1])   
    Nb = np.searchsorted(Node[:,0],Elem[i,2])
    Nc = np.searchsorted(Node[:,0],Elem[i,3])
    Nd = np.searchsorted(Node[:,0],Elem[i,4])
    print(Na,Nb,Nc,Nd)
    if i in EO:
        EleCorOx += [(Node[Na,1] + Node[Nb,1] + Node[Nc,1] + Node[Nd,1])/4]
        EleCorOy += [(Node[Na,2] + Node[Nb,2] + Node[Nc,2] + Node[Nd,2])/4]
        EleCorOz += [(Node[Na,3] + Node[Nb,3] + Node[Nc,3] + Node[Nd,3])/4]
    else:
        EleCorUx += [(Node[Na,1] + Node[Nb,1] + Node[Nc,1] + Node[Nd,1])/4]
        EleCorUy += [(Node[Na,2] + Node[Nb,2] + Node[Nc,2] + Node[Nd,2])/4]
        EleCorUz += [(Node[Na,3] + Node[Nb,3] + Node[Nc,3] + Node[Nd,3])/4]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(20,10)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(EleCorUx,EleCorUy,EleCorUz,color = 'Blue')  
ax.scatter3D(EleCorOx,EleCorOy,EleCorOz,color = 'red')
ax.set_zlim(0,27000)

plt.show()
```

This code is for showing Sektion 100. Small changes gives me the plots for 110, 120, 130 and so on.
If anyone can use it.